# ActiveMQ Artemis LDAP authentication error - Login not working

Tags: openldap, activemq-artemis

I am trying to set up authentication in activemq artemis using LDAP. Based on instructions found on the Internet, I did the configuration only in the **login.config** file. I've heard that for authentication you need to add the appropriate entries to broker.xml, but I wanted to test ldap authentication for the time being, so for the time being I only edited login.config.

And now when I specify a random user that does not exist in ldap, I get this error in the activemq console:

```
2023-10-18 23:52:51,318 WARN  [io.hawt.system.Authenticator] Login failed due to: User RandomUser not found in LDAP.
```

When I enter the correct user name, but with the wrong password, I get this message in the activemq console:

```
2023-10-18 22:39:34,771 WARN  [io.hawt.system.Authenticator] Login failed due to: Password does not match for user: User
```

When I enter the correct user name and password, no message appears in the activemq console. There is no error, nor is there any information about successful login. Only on the GUI in the browser there is an error in red about an incorrect login or password, but there is no such information in the console.

Based on these observations, I conclude that it correctly detects me users from ldap, correctly authenticates itself, because in case of a bad password I get this message. However, for some reason, after entering the correct data, it does not want to let me through.

Let me start by describing my configuration.

**LDAP User Accounts:**

```
- OU=Accounts (OU Accounts)
   - OU=A (OU A)
     - CN=User1 (USER 1)
     - CN=User2 (USER 2)
   - OU=B (OU B)
     - CN=User3 (USER 3)
```

I have individual users assigned to organizational unit

**LDAP Groups:**

**Resource groups** (ACTIVEMQ_RESOURCEGROUP) and within them, **account groups**, to which accounts **accounts** (User1, User2, User3 etc.) belong.

**login.config file:**

```
activemq {
  org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.LDAPLoginModule required
     debug=true
     initialContextFactory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
     connectionURL="ldap://ldap1.org.net.example.com:389 ldap://ldap2.org.net.example.com:389"
     connectionUsername="cn=ldap_user,ou=ACTIVEMQ,ou=Service Accounts,dc=org,dc=net,dc=example,dc=com"
     connectionPassword="ldap_password"
     connectionProtocol=s
     connectionTimeout="5000"
     authentication=simple
     userBase="ou=Accounts,dc=org,dc=net,dc=example,dc=com"
     userSearchMatching="(sAMAccountName={0})"
     userSearchSubtree=true
     readTimeout="5000"
     roleBase="ou=Resource Groups,dc=org,dc=net,dc=example,dc=com"
     roleName=ResourceGroup
     roleSearchMatching="(cn=ACTIVEMQ_RESOURCEGROUP*)"
     roleSearchSubtree=true
     ;
};
```

Comment: What role does the user you're logging in have? Does it match the role defined in `artemis.profile` for access to Hawtio? Also, does it match the role defined in `management.xml`?

Comment: I did not change any of these files. I looked at the `artemis.profile` file and changed the value from `HAWTIO_ROLE='amq'` to `HAWTIO_ROLE='*'` and it helped! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to map somehow every ldap user which is in resource group to `admin` role?

Comment: `roleBase="ou=Resource Groups,dc=org,dc=net,dc=example,dc=com"
     roleName=ResourceGroup
                                             roleSearchMatching="(cn=ACTIVEMQ_RESOURCEGROUP*)"
                  roleSearchSubtree=true` 
is it possible to match every ldap user which is in a resource group to `amq` role? Should the `roleName=amq` parameter be like that? and `roleSearchMatching=(member={0})`. I would like to assign every ldap user to existing `amq` rule? which by default is assigned to a user, which is added when creating a broker.

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram, sorry for late response, I will let you know today how I did this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem!

My working configuration:
login.config:

```
--
--
--
roleBase="ou=Resource Groups" 
roleName="cn"
roleSearchSubtree=true 
roleSearchMatching="(&(objectClass=group)(cn=<<example ABC>>)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn={0}))"
--
--
--
```

**LDAP User Accounts:**

```
- OU=Resource Groups
   - CN = ABC
///////////////////////////
- OU=Accounts (OU Accounts)
   - OU=A (OU A)
     - CN=User1 (USER 1)
     - CN=User2 (USER 2)
   - OU=B (OU B)
     - CN=User3 (USER 3)
```

Each account that is in **account group A and B**, which belong to **resource group ABC**, will receive the appropriate permissions